# Assigning Typescript constructor parameters

Tags: typescript, access-modifiers

I have interface:

```
export interface IFieldValue {
    name: string;
    value: string;
}
```

And I have a class that implements it:

```
class Person implements IFieldValue{
    name: string;
    value: string;
    constructor (name: string, value: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

after reading [this post](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/04/stop-manually-assigning-typescript-constructor-parameters/) I've thinking about refactoring:

```
class Person implements IFieldValue{
    constructor(public name: string, public value: string) {
    }
}
```

Question : In first class I have fields which by default should be as `private`. In second sample I can only set them as `public`. Is it all correct in my understanding of default Access modifiers in TypeScript?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Public by default.
> [TypeScript Documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

In following definition

```
class Person implements IFieldValue{
    name: string;
    value: string;
    constructor (name: string, value: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Attributes `<Person>.name` and `<Person>.value` are public by default.

as they are here

```
class Person implements IFieldValue{
    constructor(public name: string, public value: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**Beware:** Here is an incorrect way of doing it, since `this.name` and `this.value` will be regarded as not defined in the constructor.

```
class Person implements IFieldValue{
    constructor(name: string, value: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

To make these attributes private you need to rewrite it as

```
class Person implements IFieldValue{
    private name: string;
    private value: string;
    constructor (name: string, value: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

or equivalently

```
class Person implements IFieldValue{
    constructor (private name: string, private value: string) {}
}
```

For **TypeScript 2.X** since the interace has the properties as public, you need to change the `private` to `public` and also `export` the classes

```
export class Person implements IFieldValue{
    constructor (public name: string, public value: string) {}
}
```

which in my opinion is the most preferable way that avoids redundancy.

Comment: If `Person` implements `IFieldValue` which has public properties 'name' and 'value' then `name` and `value` must remain `public` in the `Person` class. The two code examples you provided do not compile with TypeScript 2.x. You either change the interface and make props private or you could have private props `personName` and `personValue` like: `class Person implements IFieldValue{
    private personName: string;
    private personValue: string;
    constructor (public name: string, public value: string) {
        this.personName = name;
        this.personValue = value;
    }
}`

Comment: sorry disregard the part where I said: *"You either change the interface and make props private"* makes no sense since props are only public on an interface

Comment: fwiw, I guessed wrong when dealing with an injected parameter I wanted to declare `private`. Still works like above, but the `@Inject` comes _before_ the private. `@Inject(MyType) private _myType: MyType,`

Comment: @phil_lgr I have updated the answer with important clarifications for TypeScript 2.X